# Remove menubar from Finder in Electron on OSX

Tags: macos, menu, electron, menubar

I purchased a new macbook and I am now working on getting my apps to run on a 64bit mac.

However I haven't been able to remove the default menubar.

Is there anyway to change my app name from Electron to something else within Electron via app.js so I don't see Electron in Finder (revert to screenshot for better understanding)? Is there any way to remove the edit, view window, and help menus?

[image: screenshot]

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "hello",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-prebuilt": "^0.33.0"
  }
}
```

**app.js**:

```
var app = require("app"),
        BrowserWindow = require("browser-window");

app.on("ready", function() {
  var mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    toolbar: false,
    "skip-taskbar": true,
    "auto-hide-menu-bar": true,
    width: 800,
    height: 600
  });

  mainWindow.loadUrl("file://" + __dirname + "/index.html");
  mainWindow.setMenuBarVisibility(false);
  mainWindow.setAutoHideMenuBar(true);
  mainWindow.openDevTools();
});
```

**index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello world!
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got same problem here with my electron app

I tried `mainWindow.setMenu(null);` but it didn't work

but I noticed that when app is running, there was an electron icon show in the dock which is your app

I think maybe this is the point to cause the problem here

just give it a try

```
app.dock.hide();
```

**Notice: it's an os x only method ([documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appdockhide-macos))**

there you go

[image]

after hide dock icon, you app no longer have default functions of ApplicationMenu or dockMenu, such as Quit, About, Hide etc...

so you can consider about give your app a [Tray](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.37.3/api/tray/#tray)

Answer (score 9):

After you create your browser window do the following:

```
mainWindow.setMenu(null);
```

[Only works for Windows and Linux!](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#winsetmenumenu-linux-windows) - http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#winsetmenumenu-linux-windows

Otherwise you can create a custom menu of your own by checking out Electron's documentation on the Menu: http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/menu/.

Comment: I tried that too and didn't work. I'm assuming it's part of the electron prebuilt I got from npm. I'm gonna install an older version and see if that'll fix the problem

Comment: Did you try making a custom menu and setting that?

Comment: Yeah I followed this tutorial and it didn't initiate, I still got stuck with the default menubar - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K-H2amwQ_pU

Comment: I went back over 10 versions of electron and still had the same problem. So I moved to using node-webkit, which also has 32bit mac support.

Comment: That menu api you linked is for the contextmenu, not the ribbon bar the top menu ^_^ :) Edit: Nervermind, the example is the second example my bad.

Answer (score 5):

The name Electron is in the `Info.plist` file inside Electron.app, change it to what you want.

Comment: This was very helpful. Due to electron-prebuilt, when I do `electron .` it doesn't change my app name in the first menu entry (bolded on OSX) because that's the app name. Once I package the app it works, so that's good to know.